# Fix differentiate ids that are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed to fix a select, because I have the same `id_question` for different questions.

In the example below, `id` `297914` has 2 `id_question` with value `'3'` but the correct one would be `'3'` and `'3A'`

**wrong way**

| id | id_question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 297914 | 3 | aaa |
| 297914 | 3 | bbb |
| 297933 | 3 | ccc |
| 297933 | 3 | ddd |

**correct way**

| id | id_question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 297914 | 3 | aaa |
| 297914 | 3B | bbb |
| 297933 | 3 | ccc |
| 297933 | 3B | ddd |

Is there any way to fix this?

[SQL Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1630721/differentiate-ids-that-are-the-same)

```
CREATE TABLE #form 
(
  [id] int, 
  [id_question] varchar(2), 
  [answer] varchar(10)
 );

INSERT INTO #form
(
  [id], [id_question], [answer]
)
VALUES
    (297914, '3', 'aaa'),
    (297914, '3', 'bbb'),
    (297933, '3', 'ccc'),
    (297933, '3', 'ddd')


SELECT * FROM #form
```

Comment: "the correct one would be '3' and '3A'", so where does `3B` come from?

Comment: Actually the name doesn't matter, I need to differentiate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple flag to identify the first match work?

```
 select
    id, id_question,
    case when row_number() over(partition by id,id_question order by answer) = 1 then 1 else 0 END AS is_valid,
    answer      
FROM
    #form
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger - I modified it as in most scenarios there would be another criteria for sort than id. I just chose that as no criteria was given.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` to find the duplicate values, then `UPDATE` the table appending `ASCII` characters starting with `@ + 1`, in which `A` follows `@` (See [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)).

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                              ORDER BY id_question DESC, answer DESC) AS RN
    FROM #form)
UPDATE CTE SET id_question= id_question+CHAR(ASCII('@') + 1)
WHERE RN > 1;
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7259c535957d8ab8516f3bac8b73dab1)

Result:

| id | id_question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 297914 | 3A | aaa |
| 297914 | 3 | bbb |
| 297933 | 3A | ccc |
| 297933 | 3 | ddd |